# shell script to monitor disk usage

Tags: bash, operating-system

Hi I am stuck on a piece of homework and I'm hoping for some help. The question is:

1. In the admin home directory, write a shell script that monitors disk space, namely the biggest top ten directories (N.B. Use the du command with appropriate options).
2. Store the script file in the /scripts subdirectory, owned by l-user_01.

I've tried for ages looking at notes and online but haven't found anything helpful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Steps in your question are quite clear. for step 1 you have to write a bash script by using the 'du' command to name the biggest top ten directory. Search on google for options of 'du' command to do the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this start:

```
du -sk <full-path-to-dir-to-watch>/* | sort -nr | head -n 10
```

du command will give you disk usage in blocks for all files/folders in that place you should be watching, sort with -n will sort by first column (usage figures), -r will reverse (print largest numbers 1st), then head will give you the first 10 items, the largest.

Put this in the shell script, etc... (you know better what else you wish to do)

Comment: Thanks a lot :), think I was just overthinking it and making it more complicated than it was